# Bing maps draggable infobox

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, bing-maps

I have pretty simple question. Is it possible to create draggable infobox with Bing Maps Javascrtipt API?
Ergo when i click on pushpin on map the infobox will be shown and will be draggable within the map div.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is here [ BingMap with draggable pushpin and draggable infobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275894/draggable-and-clickable-pushpin-in-javascript-bing-map/48379900#48379900)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't built in, but you could create a custom infobox control that could do this. This isn't something I've seen anyone ask for before, so not aware of any blogs out there with samples. You would have to use the mouse events to do this.